# Any idea why this Processing sketch runs so slow?

Tags: performance, processing

I'm using processing 2.1.
Any idea why my simple sketch is running slow on my (powerful) machine?

I'm simply drawing some quads in a grid, and when pressing the mouse I was trying to animate them (via Ani library), but the animation is sloppy and superslow....Any hint?

```
import de.looksgood.ani.*;
import de.looksgood.ani.easing.*;

int quadSize = 30;
int spacing = 10;
int numRows = 11;
int numColumns = 22;

float angleRotationIncrease = 3;

void setup () {
 size (900, 600, P3D);
 background (0);  
 fill (255);
 stroke (255);
 Ani.init(this);
 frameRate (60);
}



void draw () {
    text(frameRate,20,20);
    // println (angleRotationIncrease);
    background (0);
    int posX = 0;
    int posY = 0;
    int angleRotation = 0;

    float scaleFactor = 1;
    float scaleFactorIncrease = -0.045;
    for (int i=0; i<numRows; i++) {
       for (int j=0; j<numColumns; j++) {
          pushMatrix();
          translate (posX + quadSize/2, posY + quadSize/2);
          // println (radians(angleRotation));
          rotate(radians(angleRotation));
          if (scaleFactor > 0) {
            rect (-quadSize/2 * scaleFactor, -quadSize/2* scaleFactor, quadSize* scaleFactor, quadSize* scaleFactor);
          }
          popMatrix ();
          posX += (quadSize + spacing);
          angleRotation += angleRotationIncrease;
          scaleFactor += scaleFactorIncrease;
       } 
       // for each new line, reset or change params
       scaleFactorIncrease -= 0.002;
       scaleFactor = 1;
       angleRotation = 0;
       posX = 0;
       posY += (quadSize + spacing);
    }
}


void mousePressed() {
  Ani.to(this, 20, "angleRotationIncrease", -3);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved. it was a casting problem. Anglerotation is an int, so when subtracting the value I'm animating via Ani, it gets rounded

Answer (score 0):

Because you are animating low range of values over very long period of time

```
Ani.to(this, 20, "angleRotationIncrease", -3);
```

Your range is [3,-3] and time is 20 seconds. Just try to decrease time and increase range an you will see more fluent animation on your powerful machine :) like this:

```
Ani.to(this, 2, "angleRotationIncrease", -30);
```

But at the end of animation is some kind of slowing what should be specified by default by `Ani` library so for more information read documentation [here](http://www.looksgood.de/libraries/Ani/reference/de/looksgood/ani/Ani.html#to%28java.lang.Object,%20float,%20java.lang.String,%20float%29)

Comment: thx but it doesn't explain why the animation lasts like 5 frames. If you uncomment println (angleRotationIncrease) , you will see the animation should have lot of more steps that the one you can actually seen

Comment: Yes but animation change value of `float angleRotationIncrease` which is added to `int angleRotation` so in result you change angle only once in while. Try change angle to `float` then you will see more steps of animation.

Comment: crossposting, look at my own answer just posted :)

Comment: Yea looks like we posted it at same time :)

Comment: if you want to change your answer with the correct one, I will marked yours as accepted - for your help